# What's the most common way of having a consumer read messages out of a pub/sub topic and write them into a NoSQL database?

Tags: python, database, apache-spark, apache-kafka, publish-subscribe

I only need to do minimal parsing on each message, namely tokenize by commas, convert to int, and write into the database.

I intend to write a Python script as a consumer and have that run on containers in case I need to scale up. I'm most likely going to use Google Pub/sub for the pub sub engine, but I imagine I would have the same questions if I switched over to Kafka.
A couple of questions I have:

1. Will it be much better if I wrote my consumer in Java? (E.g. Would it be faster and would I need to scale the consumer script less?)
2. Should I instead be using something like Apache Spark as the consumer? I don't like the idea of needing to deal with Spark's micro-batching or dStream RDDs for something "this simple".
3. Should I be using something else entirely as the consumer? (I'm not too familiar with these but I've heard of them: Kafka Streams, Apache Storm, Flink, Beam)

Comment: Have you looked at Kafka Connect? It can do simple transforms and has some connectors already available for a bunch of common databases. http://connectors.confluent.io. This is a minimal coding solution

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your load, your current and your potential future requirements, your familiarity with various tools and frameworks etc. 
I will focus on Kafka, as I am familiar with it. The semantics of Google Pub/Sub or Kinesis are similar, so the following should be applicable.

About 1)

Json deserialization performance may vary from language to language, but it is an in-memory operation. Thus, I doubt it will be the bottleneck in your pipeline. 
There are multiple json encoders/decoders for each language, which means there is room for optimisation within a language's tool family.
A small benchmark for python based ones can be found [here](http://artem.krylysov.com/blog/2015/09/29/benchmark-python-json-libraries/).
My point here is, you shouldn't probably use a language you are not familiar with; you can probably find a performant solution in your preferred language.

In a benchmark I did some time ago, a single Kafka Consumer, on Flink, written in Scala, on AWS, fetched and deserialized Json messages (~1-2KB each) from Kafka at ~3K/s. This is to provide an indication of the order of magnitude you should expect from each parallel process. 
This was far from optimized, I am pretty sure this can be up to an order of magnitude higher if optimized properly.
My point here is, if the number of messages you except are in the 100s/1Ks per second ballpark, you shouldn't worry that much.
You could easily set up an experiment like [this](http://activisiongamescience.github.io/2016/06/15/Kafka-Client-Benchmarking/), with json messages
and add just add a json deserialisation step on top.

About 2, 3)

Spark Streaming is the exact same type of system as Flink and Storm. They are distributed stream processors able to deploy large (and stateful) streaming topologies and can scale to 100K-1M messages/s. However, they need to be deployed on a cluster (I usually choose Yarn, but it can be Mesos, or as a standalone or on Kubernetes etc). 
They may be an overkill for the use case you describe.

[Kafka consumer groups](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers) evenly distribute topic partitions within the consumers of that group. If a consumer dies, the partitions assigned to it will be load balanced between the remaining consumers. If another consumer is added, partitions will be rebalanced. The consumers mark their progress by commiting offsets to Kafka, so Kafka knows exactly where a consumer was left in case of failure. There are situations where processed offsets will fail to be committed and thus reprocessed (at least once semantics), but assuming your actions are designed to be idempotent you will be fine.

You can design a solution where a number of parallel stateless Kafka consumers are processing and persisting messages on a fleet of containers and achieve your goals.
I am under the impression that [Connect Transforms](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-66%3A+Single+Message+Transforms+for+Kafka+Connect) (as @dawsaw mentioned) is too bleeding edge, but I may be wrong.